# PHP sqlsrv_query execution syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute SQL query via PHP, where I database configuration stored in a separate file.

Below are the PHP file :

File : db_config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_DATABASE', "androidhive"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "MAVERICK"); // db server
?>
```

File : db_connect.php

```
<?php

/** A class file to connect to database */

class DB_CONNECT
{
    // constructor
        function __construct() 
    {
            // connecting to database
            $this->connect();
        }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() 
    {
            // closing db connection
            $this->close();
        }

    /** Function to connect with database */
    function connect()
    {
            // import database connection variables
            require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

           // Connecting to SQL Server database
            $serverName = DB_SERVER; 
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>DB_DATABASE);       
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo) or die(sqlsrv_errors());  
        return $conn;
    }

    /** Function to close the database connection */
    function close()
    {
        sqlsrv_close();
    }
}
?>
```

File : get_all_products.php

```
<?php 
/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = sqlsrv_query($db,"SELECT * FROM products");

if( $result ) {
     echo "Query executed.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Query could not executed.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Unfortunately , it is returning. The database connection is successful. I am struggling to find why sqlsrv_query is not working.

```
Query could not executed.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )
```

Any help on this would be very helpful.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Wer is your sql username and password, I guess it required to make sql connection please check it.

Comment: I am using SQL Windows Authentication. Thus it is eliminated with sqlsrv_connect(). Please REFER url (Example 2) : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Assign the db connection object to a class member.

```
function __construct() 
{
    // connecting to database
    $this->db_conn = $this->connect();
}
```

Then use it as:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($db->db_conn,"SELECT * FROM products");
```

Comment: I tried it , it is not working. It is redirecting me to HTTP 500 page

Comment: Put a try/catch block for sqlsrv_query(). The query might be throwing an exception.